# Getting continuous input from a button in unity2d

Tags: android, button, input, unity-game-engine, 2d

What is the equivalent of GetKey for buttons. In my android game when user press and holds the button , i want player to move right but it only moves for one time when i press the button.But when i get input from a keyboard with GetKey function , it moves until i stop holding that button. I want to use my button like GetKey.I tried to add a event trigger pointer down component into my button but it is not working.What should i do?[image]

```
public void moveRight(){
    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed,rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
}

void Update () {

    if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)){
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(rigidbody2D.velocity.x, jumpHigh);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed,rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed,rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    }

}
```

they are absolutely same but i don't understand why its not working continously.
Update method is the key, i know this but i don't know how to get information about is a button pressed in Update method.Stuck help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have two different parts of `Unity3D` API here.
Let's split it up into pieces:

### Input.GetKey

As stated in API [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html), Input.GetKey just checks if certain key is **pressed**:

> Returns true while the user holds down the key identified by name. Think auto fire.

If you check it every frame, (`Update()` is executed every frame) you re-check if button is pressed and if so, proceed with **velocity** change.

### EventTrigger

EventTriggers are a little different. They actually bind a `delegate` (`UnityAction` to be precise) you pass to them and trigger it as callbacks on given [`EventTriggerType`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTriggerType.html) fired. So if you bind to `OnPointerDown()` with your `moveRight()`, it will fire when pointer goes down over `GameObject`. If you keep the button pressed, it won't fire again because actual event of pointer going down has already happened and it already fired appropriate trigger you passed to it. Pointer is actually not going down right now. It's pressed.

It all goes down to the fact that one part checks every frame if button **is pressed** while the other one **fires when button press happens**.

Comment: Okay it makes sense . But how can i check for is a certain button pressed or not in update() function?

Comment: That depends on how often you want to do any action based on whether button is pressed or not? If you want to actually do it **per frame**, doing it via `Update()` is a way to go. If you don't want to do it per frame but per certain amount of time (I will take it as 0.1s), you can create a `Coroutine`, start it via `StartCoroutine()` on `EventTrigger` and `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f)` from it `while (Key.IsPressed("YourKey")) {}`. To be precise, there is not even an `EventTrigger` for certain key pressed in *Unity3D*.

Comment: I might not have stated it clearly but: the way you do it right now is the way *Unity3D* intends you to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.i will continue to my research.You were very helpful man thank you